# How can I get the timestamp in days in awk?

Tags: bash, date, awk, timestamp

I have a file "file_XYZ_18548".
Here the name's ending 18548 is a timestamp in days, and it is changing day by day, like "file_XYZ_18550".
I would like to get this date via variable but I couldn't find a date command to get the timestamp in days.

I can get the date result but I can't get the timestamp in reverse.

```
timeinday=18550
timestp=timeinday*86400
datetm=$(echo $timestp | gawk '{print(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $0))}')
echo $datetm
2020-10-14 10:09:10
```

How can I get this with date command in bash scripting? Is there any way of this via awk/gawk etc..?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: @anubhava 18548 days is about 50.8 years, so I guess it's days since the Unix epoch.

Comment: @anubhava ; 18548 is timestamp in days as far as i know. 

i ve edited the question.

Comment: Using awk: `awk -v dt='18550' 'BEGIN{ print(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", dt*86400)) }'`

Comment: Do you need to do this for just 1 string (e.g. a command argument) or for multiple strings (e.g. a multi-line input file or stream)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `2020-10-14` - `18548` days corresponds to `1970-01-03`, it is reasonable to guess that the 'epoch' for the day count is 1970-01-01.  It is likely that day 1 was 1970-01-01, so day zero was 1969-12-31.

#### Converting day count to date

You can use the GNU [`date`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html#date-invocation) command like this:

```
daycount=18548
date -u -d "@$(( ($daycount-1) * 86400 ))" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

That yields the result `2020-10-12 00:00:00`.  You can drop the time component of the format if you wish (you probably do; midnight isn't very exciting when it is always midnight).  You can calibrate the `-1` to resolve exactly what day should correspond to `18548`.  Just in case it isn't obvious, there are 86,400 seconds in a day (24 hours • 60 minutes per hour • 60 seconds per minute).

The `$(( … ))` notation is Bash's [Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) notation.

#### Converting current time to day count

If you want to convert the current time to the day offset, then you can use the `%s` specifier to get the seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00Z and divide by 86400 to get the number of days:

```
echo $(( $(date +'%s') / 86400 ))
```

which (at 2020-10-14 23:30 -06:00, aka 1602739800 seconds since the Unix Epoch) yields the result:

```
18550
```

Again, if need be, you can adjust the value of the division to account for when day 1 was in this scheme.  Shell arithmetic in Bash is integer arithmetic, which is exactly what is wanted.  You might need to use `-u` to get UTC as the time zone (as I did earlier), and so on.